# Proper way of handling scopes with pivot involved

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

As a laravel user for a couple of months now, I'm trying to better understand advanced use of Eloquent.

I ran into a case where I can't come up with a solution that feels right.

I've got the following structure (simplified)

```
Mandate
id
status_id

Mandate_user
mandat_id
user_id
link_status

User
id
```

I declared belongsToMany in both User and Mandat via the pivot table.

on User:

```
 public function mandates(){
        return belongsToMany(..)->withPivot('link_status');
    }
```

I'm able to get accepted mandates for a user by using

```
public function acceptedMandates(){
     return $this->mandates()->wherePivot('link_status', MandateUserStatus::Accepted);
}
```

This works but I'm wondering if there would be a better way by using scopes or other eloquent methods.
And I'm trying to get accepted mandates that also have a status_id lower than 4 (which comes from an enum as well)

I thought of something like :

```
public function runningMandates(){
     return $this->acceptedMandates()->where('status_id','<', 4);
}
```

Then gathering mandates like so:

```
$mandates = User::find(1)->runningMandates();
```

But would the eloquent way be of doing something like:

```
$mandates = User::find(1)->mandates()->running()->accepted();
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `scopes` add constraints to the query so you may use the `scope` approach to modify the query by calling scope methods that will eventually give you a chance to make a query dynamically. So, you may declare (as you did) one relationship method where you may do all the query and call that specific method or use scope methods two build the query using method calls where each method adds a constraint. In this case, it'll be more dynamic but still it's a preference and it gives you more flexibility (IMO). So yes, you can use query scopes for that, for example:

```php
// Declare the main relationship
public function mandates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(..)->withPivot('link_status');
}
```

Now, declare query scope for `accepted` (add a constraint on the query returned by `mandates` method call)

```php
public function scopeAccepted($query)
{
    return $query->wherePivot('link_status', MandateUserStatus::Accepted);
}
```

Now, add another query scope for `running`, for example:

```php
public function scopeRunning($query)
{
    return $query->where('status_id','<', 4);
}
```

Now, if you call something likethe following:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
```

Now, call the relationship method (not as property)

```php
$mendates = $user
->mandates() // The method is called and a query object is constructed
->running() // Add another constraint into the query: ->where('status_id','<', 4)
->accepted() // Add another constraint into the query: ...
->get(); // Finally, execute the query to get the result
```

Probably, it's clear to you now. Notice the method call `mandates()`, it's a method call on the relation defined which returns the `Query Builder` and by chaining additional scope method calls, you are just modifying the query by adding some more constraints but you can do all the query in one method without dynamic scopes, so it's up to you. While, scopes gives you more flexibility but it doesn't mean you've to follow this approach always, it depends.

Comment: Thanks for the example. A question though, as @Thomas pointed out in his answer, the accepted scope would be dependant on previous call to mandates() right ? otherwise pivot is null

Answer (score 3):

It's a very subjective question and hard to give a straight answer to, but hopefully I can stop you from second-guessing yourself: what you're doing is perfectly fine and no less "eloquent-like" than the other.

Personally I like what you're doing now much more than what you present as the "Eloquent way" and have done so before in professional projects, but ultimately there is a difference in the way you design the code for a framework or package, which must be flexible to account for many different scenarios, most of which you cannot even envision when doing version one, versus how you design the code for an app which will only be consumed by itself. If you know the *business logic* that drives your app and the views it will present to its users (subsequently, the queries it must perform), why wouldn't you create methods that will easily achieve just that?

Eloquent relies on chaining not just because it's cool, but because it does not know (or care to know) what your business logic is. To me, the "Eloquent way" is more about fluent, readable code, and I find that `$user->runningMandates` is more readable than `$user->mandates()->running()->accepted()->get()`.

I also find that the first approach is easier to get into. If you're constantly forcing yourself to separate methods so they can be chained, it can be harder to grasp which method is doing what and which method relies on which. Query scopes can modify the query as they like (join, alias, etc) so the danger lies in one method requiring another to come first, because you're conditioning based on a table or column that isn't on the original query, so a method will only work in conjunction with another; or maybe two methods are trying to join the same table, or using the same aliases, so they cannot be used together. It may seem far-fetched, but often the effort to keep things separate and tidy will make your code harder to use. But even if things don't blow up code-wise, the deal-breaker to me would be neglecting business logic: in your case, does it make sense to have two separate scopes for `running` and `accepted`? Can a mandate be `running` if it's not accepted? If not, you should try to prevent a less knowledgeable developer from creating that flawed query (logic-wise). And as you said, the structure is simplified so there may be other gotchas lurking around, and many more will come as the app grows in complexity.

If I'm taking over someone else's code, I'd rather have limited, self-contained methods that don't break over simple, decentralized methods that require you to read (often non-existent) documentation in order to prevent the many ways in which to mis-use them.

Comment: Thanks! 
I also prefer my approach but asked myself as the application was getting bigger and bigger and my user model getting longer. I will probably adapt and use a bit both depending on the context.